# Graphics Acceleration Error in BlackBerry Simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

When I run any program on simulator it opens and shows an error :

> Graphics acceleration error - BlackBerry 9900 Simulator
>
> A problem was detected with your current graphics acceleration
>   settings.  An OpenGL 1.x+ compatible video card with recent video
>   drivers is required for graphics acceleration.  Please try a lower
>   graphics acceleration setting by navigating to the view menu.
>
> The simuator will now revert back to software rendering.
>
> Could not create texture (err=0x501)

Need help on this.

Answer (score 13):

I develop with Blackberry SDK for Eclipse (plugin) and I appeared the same problem.

I solved by adding the line `<BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>0</BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>` in file  fledge-settings.conf found in the following directory `C: \ eclipse \ plugins \ net.rim.ejde . componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10 \ components \ simulator`

If this line exists only change the value that is between the tags <> value <> to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

Navigate to the folder where eclipse has installed. In my case it has installed on desktop. ie `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\eclipse\`
After this navigate to the plugin folder -> `Blackberry Installed SDK folder -> Components -> Simulator`. Then try to search for file `fledge-settings.conf` . Open this using Notepad or any editor. Add the below line

```
<BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>0</BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>
```

before `</fledge-configuration>` tag.

Path to navigate `fledge-settings.conf` file:

C:\Users\Username\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\components\simulator

[More info](http://www.flickr.com/photos/48436294@N05/8354219539/)

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Graphics Acceleration. For BlackBerry Torch 9800 simulator, where to find turning off option (red marker) is shown in following image. Try something like that on your simulator.

[image]

Comment: Got the same problem and the emulator crashes (forced shutdown) before I can even touch the settings. :C Is there another way to edit the configuration?

Comment: I tried the solution of levi and the simulator works now thanks for Help :D