# How to handle this error? "Graphics acceleration error - BlackBerry 9900 Simulator"

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

> Graphics acceleration error - BlackBerry 9900 Simulator
>
> A problem was detected with your current graphics acceleration settings.  An OpenGL 1.x+ compatible video card with recent video drivers is required for graphics acceleration.  Please try a lower graphics acceleration setting by navigating to the view menu.
>
> The simuator will now revert back to software rendering.
>
> Could not create texture (err=0x501)

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844265/graphics-acceleration-error-in-blackberry-simulator) but I got stuck at the same problem where answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844265/graphics-acceleration-error-in-blackberry-simulator) stopped.

How I can handle this issue?

Answer (score 3):

```
fledge /graphics-acceleration=0
```

Comment: To expand on this, if you add this flag (`/graphics-acceleration=0`) at the end of `9900.bat` (in the dir you installed the emulator in) this should force it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can hand edit the BlackBerry smartphone simulator configuration file to disable graphics acceleration.  Look in C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\net\rim\fledge-2 and you should see a bunch of .conf files for the simulators you have installed.  Open fledge-saved.conf in a text editor and change (3 to 0):

```
<BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>3</BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>
```

to:

```
<BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>0</BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>
```

That will disable graphics acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find that tag then just paste the tag with the value 0 in your `fledge-settings.conf` file.

Comment: it works for me after pasting the the above tag in my fledge-settings.conf file

Answer (score 1):

like MSohm said, you can disabled graphic acceleration through C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\net\rim\fledge-2 set

```
<BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>3</BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>
```

to

```
<BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>0</BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>
```

If you can't find the tag already in the file, just add the setting

```
<BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>0</BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>
```

before `</fledge-configuration>`

hope this helps. in my case, I couldn't find the setting, and I just add it, and it works fine.

Comment: The folder `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\net\rim\fledge-2` is empty for me. What to do now ?